# serial scroller problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with serial scroller :

**Markup:**

```
<div id="scroller">    
      <ul style="width: 1200px;" id="items_scroller">    
        <li> aaa </li>
        <li> bbb </li>
        <li> ccc </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
  $('#scroller').serialScroll({
    items:'li:visible',
    prev:'a#left_scroller',
    next:'a#right_scroller',
    axis:'x',
    offset:0,
    start:0,
    stop:false,
    onBefore:serialScrollFixLock,
    duration:700,
    step: 1,
    lazy: false,
    interval:5000,
    lock: false,
    force:false,
    cycle:true
  });
```

**css :**

```
#scroller{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 90px;
  width: 800px;

  }

#items_scroller li{
  float:left; 
  width:400px;
  height: 75px; 
  padding: 0px;
  position:relative;
  margin-left:0px;
  }
```

The problem is when it is going to the end of right site it's waiting twice more 10 second before it is return to the beginning.

It looks like scroller counts one more item but I think that the markup and code is correct.

Comment: please edit your question, repaste the html and css, and use the `{}` button in the editor to format them as code blocks.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: I've attempted to make a JSFiddle for the OP using the supplied code and including the SerialScroller plugin - http://jsfiddle.net/Edcgh/ - but it's not working for me at all. Probably missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "exclude" option for serialScroll, I think this may resolve your problem: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html